# Sending forgot password emails using blowfish

Tags: php, blowfish, forgot-password

This is stored in a database. How do I send this demo password to my user? I cant convert this ($2y$10$Zjk5YzQ4ZTlhMzNlNTUzMO3Wnm1FqXmAb6/4DmyptNGoEdWGLwls.) to normal text.

Is there any solution? I'm also unable to send random password.

```
demo = $2y$10$Zjk5YzQ4ZTlhMzNlNTUzMO3Wnm1FqXmAb6/4DmyptNGoEdWGLwls.
```

Here are some functions I used for password checking and generation:

```
function password_encrypt($password) {
  $hash_format = "$2y$10$";   // Tells PHP to use Blowfish with a "cost" of 10
  $salt_length = 22;                    // Blowfish salts should be 22-characters or more
  $salt = generate_salt($salt_length);
  $format_and_salt = $hash_format . $salt;
  $hash = crypt($password, $format_and_salt);
    return $hash;
}

function generate_salt($length) {
  // Not 100% unique, not 100% random, but good enough for a salt
  // MD5 returns 32 characters
  $unique_random_string = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
    // Valid characters for a salt are [a-zA-Z0-9./]
  $base64_string = base64_encode($unique_random_string);
    // But not '+' which is valid in base64 encoding
  $modified_base64_string = str_replace('+', '.', $base64_string);
    // Truncate string to the correct length
  $salt = substr($modified_base64_string, 0, $length);
    return $salt;
}

function password_check($password, $existing_hash) {
    // existing hash contains format and salt at start
  $hash = crypt($password, $existing_hash);
  if ($hash === $existing_hash) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the actual question you're asking. What do you mean by a "demo password"?

Comment: If a user forgets their password, then they should be sent a link containing a randomly generated token that (for a limited time and one use only) can be used to get a form that will allow a new password to be set. You shouldn't be sending the hashed password to the user.

Comment: Your choice of hashing algorithm doesn't change best practises for how to handle a password reset.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good scheme for password recovery, to generate a new password and send it to the user. Instead send the user a link with a random independend code, and store this code in your database (hashed). When the user clicks the link, then let him enter a new password. There is no need to know the old password then, the user is authenticated when he can read the email (his email address).

A forgotten password form, can be posted by everybody: You wouldn't be happy if somebody entered your email, and your password was changed immediately. Retrieving the link, you have the opportunity to either ignore the email, or to confirm that you really want to change the password.

As you correctly pointed out, passwords should be stored as hash, and therefore cannot be retrieved. As soon as the hash of the password is stored in the database, there should be no further need to know the real password. Whenever you need the password later, you will know it, because the user entered it.

To generate the BCrypt hash, i would recommend to use the PHP function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), there exists also a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for earlier PHP versions. Especially the generation of the salt is solved much better there.

P.S.
The hash you described is called BCrypt, it is based on the blowfish cipher which is used for two-way encryption.